# Reason for IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, multithreading

I am getting an Illegal State exception for following code :

```
synchronized (this) {
        try {
        Thread.currentThread().wait();
        notifyAll();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }
```

What i could made is synchronized on "this" will capture Monitor on Object calling the method and since i am calling wait on Current Thread object and i really don't have lock on that i am getting t error. Please validate my theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call wait on the current thread, call it on this.

```
this.wait();
```

but then you will never get a `notifyAll` , because no thread that enters the synchronized block
can ever reach the `notofyAll` method. They all will wait for it first.

I guess you want one Thread to wait for another Thread to do some work.

Here is a short example of how synchronization between threads can work

```
public class ThreadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Object monitor = new Object();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new R1(monitor));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new R2(monitor));

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        t2.join();
        t1.join();
    }

    public static class R1 implements Runnable {

        private Object monitor;

        public R1(Object monitor) {
            this.monitor = monitor;
        }

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("R1 entered run");
            synchronized (monitor) {
                try {
                    monitor.wait();
                    System.out.println("R1 got monitor back");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static class R2 implements Runnable {

        private Object monitor;

        public R2(Object monitor) {
            this.monitor = monitor;
        }

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("R2 entered run");
            synchronized (monitor) {
                System.out.println("R2 will sleep for 1 sec");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out
                            .println("R2 will notify all threads waiting for monitor");
                    monitor.notifyAll();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Output is:

```
R1 entered run
R2 entered run
R2 will sleep for 1 sec
R2 will notify all threads waiting for monitor
R1 got monitor back
```

Answer (score 0):

You have acquired the lock of

> this(current object)

and you are calling `

> wait()

` on current thread that is why.

you should acquire lock before calling wait, notify notifyAll

Answer (score 0):

Case1

```
...
synchronized(this){
   this.wait();
}
...
```

Case2

```
...
synchronized(this){
   Thread.currentThread.wait();
}
...
```

Case 1 is sensible code. It waits until another thread calls `notify[All]()` on "`this`" object.

Case 2 looks silly. It could only execute if the current thread and "`this`" were the same object, or you already had a lock on the current thread. Otherwise, you'd get `IllegalMonitorStateException`. Synchronising on Thread objects is a Bad Thing, because you can't be sure what else might be synchronising on them.

By the way, if what you want to do is just pause for a while in the program, you should `sleep()`, not `wait()`.

Answer (score 0):

From the Java doc for Object class wait() method:

> IllegalMonitorStateException - if the current thread is not the owner
>   of the object's monitor.

In your code, current thread is the owner of the monitor of `this` and `wait` is called on `Thread.currentThread`.

Replace `Thread.currentThread().wait();` with `this.wait();`